# Add custom post type title to an array

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm attempting to change a plugin found [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/06/send-sms-notifications-new-posts-wordpress.html). It's a Twillio tutorial on assembling a plugin that sends SMS upon "publish" of a WordPress post using their systems. The hurdle I face is many posts are generated per day and I wouldn't want multiple SMS going out. That would be annoying. So, I have created a custom post type called "SMS". I am unable to configure the plugin described to use the custom post type instead of the default or "post" wordpress provides in the initial configuration.

```
// Prepares SMS to be sent when post is published

// function post_published_notifications($ID, $post ) //Original plugin function. I'm unsure of how to reassign global $post

function post_published_notification($ID) // I added this trying to access CPT, sans $post
  {

    $sid = '####################';
    $token = '######################';
    $from = '+1530#######';
    $client = new Client($sid, $token);

    $gallery_args = array(
      'post_type'=> 'SMS',
    );

    $posts_display_gallery = get_posts( $gallery_args ); // My code that doesn't work. Trying to access the CPT named SMS

    $title = $posts_display_gallery->post_title; // My code that doesn't work. Trying to assign variable to CPT title.

    //$title = $post->post_title; // gets post title. Provided by Twillio. Returns post title.

    $body = sprintf('New Post: %s', $title);

    $blogusers = get_users('blogid=$ID&role=subscriber');
    foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
      $to = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'mobile', true);
      if (intval($to) == 0) {
        continue;
      }
      $client->messages->create(
        $to,
        array(
          'from' => $from,
          'body' => $body  // Custom post type title should be held here.
        )
      );
    }
  }

  add_action('publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Can you check the `$posts_display_gallery` if the `post_title` property are coming right?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at WordPress's hooks system for binding specifically to post types, here's a link to their relevant documentation which covers this:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/

Comment: Thanks Aran.. tried a few different methods of getting SMS CPT with get_post_type(), even wrapping my SMS code in a conditional.. but I'm not getting it..